# Can a private IP address change?

Tags: google-analytics, ip

Okay, this may be a stupid question. I have setuped a `Google Analytics` account to analyze the traffic of my own site (online portfolio).

My question is: How can I exclude the traffic from me? 
Can I just simply get my public IP address and exclude it? Will it change? 
If it will, how can I effectively exclude the internal traffic? Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set up Ghostery plugin on your main browser and use only this browser for working with Your site.
Simple and very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your IP address is likely to change over time.

IP filtering is best used for corporate networks, which have static IP addresses (or range of IP addresses). IP filtering is unlikely to be useful for individuals.

The best way to filter out your own traffic would be to create a Custom Dimension for *User Type*, and have your CMS/Portfolio application fill out its value depending on visitor's log-in status.

## 1. Create a Custom Dimension in Google Analytics

Navigate to the Admin Section of Analytics, and create a new Custom Dimension for *User Type*.

> For reference and/or more details, see [the official Google
> documentation about creating Custom
> Dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en).

## 2. Create filtered Views in Analytics

Still in Google Analytics, you can set up multiple Views and use filters to remove yourself from the traffic logged.

For example:

1. Leave the default View provided as a "Raw & Unfiltered View".
2. Create a new View, "Visitors only", and apply an "Exclude Filter" based on your Custom Dimension, preventing "Administrator" hits from being displayed.

> For reference and/or more details, see the official Google
> documentation about [creating a
> View](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009714?hl=en) and
> [managing View
> filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en).

## 3. Have your CMS/Portfolio print the user status for each view

For example:

- When User is logged in as Administrator/Contributor, have the application output:

```js
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Administrator');
```

- When User is anonymous, have the application output:

```js
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Visitor');
```

Unfortunately, you might have to look for plugins and/or do code it yourself, depending on your application.

Comment: Thank you very much. But my site doesn't have a log-in module, so I can't record a user as an admin or a visitor. But thanks anyway!